# Is it possible to resize an image but keep the borders the same on iOS?

Tags: ios, image, resize, border

I have an image with a fixed border, and I need to be able to change the height of the image from for example 25px to 300px but so that the border on top only makes up the 5px it did originally. Of course the possibility is to keep as many version of the same image in different sizes, as many sizes I have, but that would take up huge amounts of memory, or I could try to rather make up one image of 5 parts, that is upper border, bottom border, left and right borders, and the actual content. This is, however, rather inconvenient

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the `UIImage` method

```
-(UIImage *)resizableImageWithCapInsets:
```

Send this message to your original image and pass `UIEdgeInsetsMake(topFixedBorderSize, leftFixedBorderSize, bottomFixedBorderSize, rightFixedBorderSize)` and you'll get back a "resizable" image.  When you draw the resizable image at a larger size only the pixels not covered by the cap insets will be stretched.  The pixels covered by the cap insets on every side will remain fixed on the edge.